# Calculate user parameters using Microsoft kinect

Tags: kinect, openkinect

I want to get the following information of a user that is captured using a Microsoft Kinect using a WPF application.

- Shoulder width
- Height
- Waist width
- Hip width
- Arm length
- Bust size

I couldn't find any standard way of doing this except calculating the x,y co-ordinates of the user. Is there any very efficient and accurate way of doing this?

Comment: Why would you use OpenKinect instead of the Kinect for Windows SDK? Seeing that you want to create a WPF application, the latter would be more convenient.

Comment: no I just want to know what ever the method using Windows SDK or Open Kinect

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can follow the article @ http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/380152/Kinect-for-Windows-Find-user-height-accurately

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to accomplish this task is using the [Pythagorean theorem](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Distance.html) to compute the distance between two skeleton joints.

To get the shoulder width, you would use the joints `JointType.ShoulderLeft` and `JointType.ShoulderRight`. The get the length of the left arm, you would add the distance between `JointType.ShoulderLeft` and `JointType.ElbowLeft` to the distance between `JointType.ElbowLeft` and `JointType.WristLeft`.

Please note that the joint names above are from the Kinect for Windows SDK. On its own, OpenKinect does not provide a method for skeleton tracking, since it's specialized on accessing the device only. A popular alternative to the Kinect for Windows SDK is [OpenNI](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/148251/How-to-Successfully-Install-Kinect-on-Windows-Open).